# How to set debug.keystore for each android project?

Tags: android, adt, android-sdk-tools

I'm developing some applications that need system UID. So I made a special keystore file "PFDebug.keystore" made from AOSP's platform.pk8 and platform.x509.pem.

I set it in Eclipse >window >preferences >android >build >cutstom debug keystore. That works fine.

But I am also developing non-privileged applications that use my own debug.keystore file. So I have to change keystore file for each build. I know that default debug.keystore is used when I set blank.

How can I bind debug keystore files for each android project?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's doable with gradle.
For each project you have a build.gradle in which you can specify a signingConfig. Like that :

```
 signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("../debug.keystore")
        }

        release {
            storeFile file("../prod.keystore")
            storePassword 'prod'
            keyAlias 'prod'
            keyPassword 'prod'
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for a good information. I think it will work on Android Studio, but can I use with current ADT on windows?

Comment: You can use Gradle with Eclipse or Android Studio, and on Windows or Mac !